# Serve static webpage only if it's requested with no extension

Tags: node.js, express

I have a HTML file named `file.html` I want it to be only served if it's requested without the `.html` extension.

So if someone requests this webpage like `mydomain.com/file.html` it should not get served. However if someone requests it without the extension such as `mydomain.com/file` then it should get served.

I tried the following:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {
    extensions: ['html', 'htm']
}));
```

The problem with the code above is that it also serves the webpage if it gets requested like `mydomain.com/file.html`

Is there a way in Express to allow html webpages to be only served if they are requested without their extension?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the request is sent with the html extension? Redirect? 404?

Comment: Yes, I would like it give 404 status error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little middleware to reject any routes ending in `.htm` or `.html` with a 404. Make sure to include this before your code above that serves the static files:

```
function forbidHTMLExtension(req, res, next) {
  let url = req.url;
  if (url.length < 4) return next();
  if (url.slice(-4) === '.htm' || url.slice(-5) === '.html') {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  next();
}
app.use(forbidHTMLExtension);
```